# Notify icon working fine in windows XP but not in windows server 2003

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, notifyicon

I have an application in which i am using notifyicon.The application is meant to run at windows startup.The application is getting started in both the OS as i can see the process in task manager but in windows server 2003 the notify icon is not visible.I am clueless why this kind of behavior.The notifyIcon is visible in windows Xp.

I came across this [NotifyIcon not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842494/notifyicon-not-showing)

but this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem by bumping up the delay at the startup with the help of a script.
Problem seems to be with windows shell.dll

Comment: The problem is the design of your application. Notification icons only work when there is a user logged in and the application is running on that user's desktop. You're trying to run this app at startup, when there are no users logged in. Change it to run whenever a user logs in by putting it in the "Startup" folder.